# Why was Linux process killed?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, process

I run an ubuntu server (14.04, kernel 3.13) that has a single process serving network traffic. The process stopped running this morning and I can't figure out why.

There are no `SIGSEGV` or out-of-memory entries in `/var/log/*`, or crash reports in `/var/crash`.

The process stopped around 22:00 on the 14th but`dmesg -T` only shows:

```
...
[Fri Aug 11 15:24:41 2017] init: upstart-socket-bridge main process (559) terminated with status 1
[Fri Aug 11 15:24:41 2017] init: upstart-socket-bridge main process ended, respawning
[Fri Aug 11 15:24:41 2017] init: upstart-file-bridge main process (810) terminated with status 1
[Fri Aug 11 15:24:41 2017] init: upstart-file-bridge main process ended, respawning
[Mon Aug 14 14:37:35 2017] Peer xx.xx.xx.xx:yyyy/zzzz unexpectedly shrunk window 2274411280:2274411310 (repaired)
```

...which doesn't appear to be relevant.

Is there another way to find out how the process died?

(Note that he process uses an epoll event loop with a timer, so it won't have terminated of its own accord)

Comment: What about the log file of the process itself?

Comment: The process' own log file doesn't have anything unusual. That said, stdout and stderr were not captured, so my current best guess is that an unhandled C++ exception could have caused the process to terminate with no useful log message being written. I've set up an exception handler as per [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13219105/does-linux-log-an-uncaught-exception-thrown-by-a-daemon).

Comment: How are you managing the process? If it's a non-daemon process, you can use Supervisor to manage it. It will also log crashes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll give supervisor a try in case this happens again.